# FullSimplify on complex numbers seems inconsistent

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

```
FullSimplify[c Conjugate[c]]
```

returns

```
Abs[c]^2
```

while

```
FullSimplify[2 c Conjugate[c]]
```

returns

```
2 c Conjugate[c]
```

This seems strange to me.  For some reason, a third entry in the Times[]  precludes the simplification with Abs[].  Is this just a shortcoming of the way FullSimplify[] is implemented, or is there some good reason for this?

It's quite annoying when I have a complicated expression and some terms are real and positive definite, but this is not immediately obvious, because FullSimplify[] is failing to combine variables with their complex conjugates.

Comment: I agree. That's irritating. Could be something to do with what *Mathematica* thinks a simplified form is, but this strikes me as silly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, `FullSimplify[ ]` has its own creed about what transformations should try and how to measure the complexity of its output.

You can coerce it to perform in some crazy ways, though:

```
exp =  2 c Conjugate[c];
SimplifyCount[p_] := First@ImageDimensions@Rasterize[p]
f[e_] := e /. Times[x___, a_, y___, Conjugate[a_], z__] :> Times[Abs[a]^2, x, y, z]
FullSimplify[exp, TransformationFunctions -> f, ComplexityFunction -> SimplifyCount]

(* 2 Abs[c]^2 *)
```

Comment: The ComplexityFunction above isn't really necessary. I show it as an example of a "crazy" thing