# Simplification fails for complex variables

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

I ran into the problem that *Mathematica*'s (full-) simplification does not replace

```
t Conjugate[t]
```

by

```
Abs[t]^2
```

In my case, I get pretty ugly expressions which greatly simplify when I replace the expressions manually. As an example:

```
FullSimplify[( 2 (-((Abs[a - b + Sqrt[(a - b)^2 + 4 t Conjugate[t]]]^2 + 
  4 t Conjugate[t])/(
 2 (a + b - 2 ω + Sqrt[(a - b)^2 + 4 t Conjugate[t]]))) + (
Abs[-a + b + Sqrt[(a - b)^2 + 4 t Conjugate[t]]]^2 + 
 4 t Conjugate[t])/(
2 (-a - b + 2 ω + 
   Sqrt[(a - b)^2 + 4 t Conjugate[t]]))))/((a - b) (Conjugate[a] -
  Conjugate[b]) + 4 t Conjugate[t] +   Sqrt[(a - b)^2 + 4 t Conjugate[t]]
Conjugate[Sqrt[(a - b)^2 + 4 t Conjugate[t]]]), {{a, 
b, ω} ∈ Reals, t ∈ Complexes}]
```

Does not yield any simplification. However, if I replace

```
t Conjugate[t] -> Abs[t]^2
```

or, if I change $t$ to be real, I find the desired result
$\frac{b-\omega}{ |t|^2-(a-\omega)(b-\omega)}$

PS: I just realized this is appears to be the same problem as posted here: [FullSimplify on complex numbers seems inconsistent](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/97285/fullsimplify-on-complex-numbers-seems-inconsistent). However I'd much appreciate a less "crazy" solution…

Comment: may be `ComplexExpand[t Conjugate[t]]`. Lookup up `ComplexExpand` in the help.

Comment: Thanks, but that does not help. In my case I get terms like `Arg[(a - b)^2 + 4 t Conjugate[t]]` which are zero as the argument is positive.

Comment: If split $t$ into real and imaginary part *explicitly*, and tell `Simplify` that both parts are real, then I find the final simplified result. But… that's not a great solution?

Comment: Adding `TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, # /. x_ Conjugate[x_] :> Abs[x]^2 &}` does give the result you want, for what it's worth.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`ComplexExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand) with a suitable [`TargetFunctions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TargetFunctions) option and [`Simplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify). Here is your expression:

```
expr = (2 (-((Abs[a - b + Sqrt[(a - b)^2 + 4 t Conjugate[t]]]^2 + 
        4 t Conjugate[t])/(2 (a + b - 2 ω + 
          Sqrt[(a - b)^2 + 4 t Conjugate[t]]))) + (Abs[-a + b + 
         Sqrt[(a - b)^2 + 4 t Conjugate[t]]]^2 + 
      4 t Conjugate[t])/(2 (-a - b + 2 ω + 
        Sqrt[(a - b)^2 + 4 t Conjugate[t]]))))/((a - b) (Conjugate[a] - 
    Conjugate[b]) + 4 t Conjugate[t] + 
 Sqrt[(a - b)^2 + 4 t Conjugate[t]] Conjugate[
   Sqrt[(a - b)^2 + 4 t Conjugate[t]]]);
```

Then, you can use:

```
Simplify[
    ComplexExpand[expr, t, TargetFunctions->{Abs}],
    (a | b | ω) ∈ Reals
]
```

> (b - ω)/((a - ω) (-b + ω) + Abs[t]^2)

Comment: Thanks, I had not looked into the documentation of ComplexExpand, properly. It bugs me that Mathematica is so sensitive form of the input, but your answer is a pretty good "workaround".